# How to prevent bookdown from deleting the .Rmd file?

Tags: r, bookdown

I use Bookdown from within RStudio. From time to time, when the document refuses to knit and I get an unhelpful error message (like this one:

```
Quitting from lines 495-497 (Mamede02.Rmd) 
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : object 'value' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... lapply -> FUN -> mean -> [ -> [.data.table -> [.data.frame
Execution halted)
```

which could mean almost anything to me, the only clue I am left with (short of bisecting the code) are the mysterious line numbers, like `495-497` in the example above. The problem is that the line numbers refer to the already-removed file, which I have no idea how to prevent from disappearing. `keep_md: yes` is not supported by `bookdown::pdf_book`...

How to prevent the `.Rmd` file from disappearing?

---

### Linux walkaround:

Use `sudo chattr +i Mamede02.Rmd` in the terminal (`Mamede02.Rmd` is the name/full path to the file you want to keep from vanishing),  but **be quick**: you need to execute this command *after* the file has been created (after you started the knitting process) and *before* the file disappears.

Answer (score 2):

With the [development version](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) of **bookdown** (>= 0.1.4) on Github, the file `Mamede02.Rmd` will not be removed if an error occurred during the rendering process.

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```